# When fullcalendar is uploaded to hosting, events do not appear on the screen

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, fullcalendar

I made an appointment system using fullcalendar. In localhost, appointments are on the calendar, but when I upload them to hosting, the appointments do not appear on the calendar. I checked the api and it works fine. What could be causing the problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iaY1w.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Do you have any error?You can try to click F12 and check it.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including all code and data **as text** within your question here. See also [ask] and the [tour]. We cannot use or fix code shown via pictures. Also the picture doesn't prove anything - we can see you have some events, but we don't know if they're valid fullCalendar event objects or not. We also can't re-use the data or code to make any tests or answers. Please provide a full example instead. You can update your post by pressing the "edit" button just under the little blue "asp.net" tag at the end of the question. After that, we can help you properly. Thanks.

Comment: @YiyiYou the error does not appear. I checked with the debugger, the data is coming in correctly, but it is not on the screen.

Comment: As per my comment earlier, you need to provide more details before we can help you any further.